# Vector equation intersect of xy-plane

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry

> Let
>   $$L: \vec r(t)=<4-2t, -7+3t,8-13t>, \qquad t \in \mathbb{R}$$
>   Does this line ever intersect xy -plane?
>   So, <4-t,-7+6t,3+2t> = < a , b, 0>, where a,b is an arbitrary constant.

Secondly,

> Let
>   $$P: \vec g(t)=<3 + t, -1 - 5t, 8t>, \qquad t \in \mathbb{R}$$
>   Does P ever intersect L?

Does that mean when vector r(t) - g(t) = 0??

Comment: L is a line, not a plane. And yes, it does intersect the xy plane. Consider the third coordinate.

Comment: you appear to have two different equations (describing two different lines in your section on $L.$

Answer (score 1):

Lines L and P do not intersect.

Let the variable in L be t1 and in P be t2. Equate the x and y coordinates. They are a system of linear equations in two variables. Solve them.

Substitute the variables in z coordinate , if they are equal then they intersect else they don't.

Here they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the equation for the $xy$ plane is given by $z = 0$. Therefore if we have intersection of this vector parametrization and plane, there must exists a $t_0$ such that $3+2t_0 = 0$. This implies $t_0 = -3/2$ and so the intersection point is $\left(\frac{11}{2},-16,0\right)$.

To get intersection of the two lines, there must exist $s_0,t_0$ such that $g(s_0) = r(t_0)$. Now just solve the system by setting coordinates equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, notice that the line is not parallel to the xy plane.

For the second question, first notice that the lines are not parallel. Now consider the system of equations $\begin{cases}4-2t_1=3+t_2\\-7+3t_1=-1-5t_2\\8-13t_1=8t_2\end{cases}$. If this system is consistent, then $P$ and $L$ intersect.

Answer (score 0):

$L$ intersects with the $XY$-plane when $z$, which is actually $8−13t$, equals zero, which happens when $t=\frac{8}{13}$, isn't it? :-)